# What do I do with this cone?

Tags: botanicula

So, I'll admit, I love point-and-click adventure games. The problem is, **I'm terrible at them!** I've been staring at this screen in *Botanicula* for close to half an hour, and I *still* have no idea what I'm supposed to do with these bouncy little cherry looking guys, and this cone.

[image]

**What do I do in this area?** (Or, have I been wasting my time staring at nothing?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The red things (Hopiks) run away from your cursor. Push them towards the funnel in the middle and then push them from below and one will jump into the funnel for an achievement.

[image: flat funnel]

Comment: The game is buggy in fullscreen. If you play in 60% or 100% windowed, they'll react better. That should do the trick. Otherwise, come at 'em from the sides and once they're somewhat close, back up and come at them from below and one will hop in. Mine hopped in from the lower branch on the right.

Comment: For some reason, the game wasn't recognizing my mouse well enough to do this. I had to resort to the touchpad.

Comment: The game is also buggy if you have a high dpi gaming mouse. If you can turn it down, it should work.